# Can't package my Kivy app into a EXE. Error = (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'the system cannot find the file specified.')

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyinstaller

I keep getting this error. I've tryed to look up for a solutions but none seem to work. I was following the instructions on Kivy's web site, editting the `.spec` file. I am executing PyInstaller through command prompt. I don't know how to do it via python code.

I'm running this in Python 3.7, in a venv with kivy installed. Windows 10.

Here is how my `.spec` is as of now:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\ynaqp\\PycharmProjects\\ControladoraKivy'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='controladora',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\ynaqp\\PycharmProjects\\ControladoraKivy\\Controler.kv',
             'C:\\Users\\ynaqp\\PycharmProjects\\ControladoraKivy\\consumo.json',
             'C:\\Users\\ynaqp\\PycharmProjects\\ControladoraKivy\\maquete.jpeg')

             # I tried specifing the files (desperate times)
               ,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='controladora')
```

Full error chart:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
25135 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
25136 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
     yield
25137 WARNING: stderr:     yield
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
25138 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
     return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
25139 WARNING: stderr:     return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
25140 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
     raise make_error(function, function_name)
25141 WARNING: stderr:     raise make_error(function, function_name)
 OSError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
25141 WARNING: stderr: OSError: [WinError 2] the system cannot find the file specified.

25142 WARNING: stderr:
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
25143 WARNING: stderr: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

25144 WARNING: stderr:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
25145 WARNING: stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
25148 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec)
25149 WARNING: stderr:     "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
25150 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
25151 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 121, in <module>
25151 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 121, in <module>
     run()
25152 WARNING: stderr:     run()
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
25153 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
25154 WARNING: stderr:     run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
25155 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
25158 WARNING: stderr:     PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
25159 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main
     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
25160 WARNING: stderr:     build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
25161 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build
     exec(code, spec_namespace)
25162 WARNING: stderr:     exec(code, spec_namespace)
   File "controladora.spec", line 19, in <module>
25163 WARNING: stderr:   File "controladora.spec", line 19, in <module>
     noarchive=False)
25164 WARNING: stderr:     noarchive=False)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
25165 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
     self.__postinit__()
25166 WARNING: stderr:     self.__postinit__()
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
25166 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
     self.assemble()
25169 WARNING: stderr:     self.assemble()
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 467, in assemble
25170 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 467, in assemble
     redirects=self.binding_redirects))
25171 WARNING: stderr:     redirects=self.binding_redirects))
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
25172 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 228, in Dependencies
     for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
25173 WARNING: stderr:     for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
25174 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 407, in getAssemblyFiles
     for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
25175 WARNING: stderr:     for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
25175 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 358, in getAssemblies
     res = GetManifestResources(pth)
25177 WARNING: stderr:     res = GetManifestResources(pth)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1000, in GetManifestResources
25179 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1000, in GetManifestResources
     return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
25181 WARNING: stderr:     return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
25181 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 170, in GetResources
     hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
25183 WARNING: stderr:     hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
25183 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
     return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
25184 WARNING: stderr:     return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
25185 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
25186 WARNING: stderr:     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
25187 WARNING: stderr:   File "C:\Users\ynaqp\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
     raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
25188 WARNING: stderr:     raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
 win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.')
25190 WARNING: stderr: win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (2, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'the system cannot find the file specified.')
```

Comment: If it helps in anything my process is:
1. Run the code `python -m PyInstaller --name MyApp main.py`.
I don't get any error here, only warnings, but the app wont even open at this state;

 2. Edit the `.spec` file and then run `python -m PyInstaller MyApp.spec`. Here is where the error appears.

Comment: In the end it was a problem with my python installation.